# Participant Status vs. Participant Status ID

Tags: civireport

Did I miss something or has there been a architectural change with these parameters? The search builder gives a list of the status options for both of these parameters, but for the Participant Status ID is throws an error: is not of the type Int

In which release has there been recent changes to this part of civicrm? And which Github or JIRA issues document that change?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything has changed.  Every participant status has both a label/name as well as an assigned ID (integer) value.  The search builder lets you construct a search using either construct.

I do see on the 4.6 sandbox, that when I select to search on Participant Status ID that its possible option values are the names rather than the ID's.... however the result set still came back correctly and displayed the ID's.

I suspect this behaviour goes back to v3 days.